# Binding properties of multiple tree views to the same ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working on a MVVM implementation, where i'll spawn multiple views (side by side) each containing a tree control.

each of the views will have a similar tree, with a copy of [almost] all the same items.

I would like to synchronize the IsExpanded property on all the view/TreeView's..

meaning, if i collapse one node, i would like all of them to collapse (and some goes for column widths etc).

One way to do this, would be to bind all views to the same viewmodel, and have a DependencyProperty on that ViewModel, and set up the binding as Two Way on each view. However, i need each view to be bound to a separate viewmodel so that it can display unique values. I just need to synchronize a few properties of the tree, such as IsExpanded and Width.

What would be the best approach here?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you can't have different collections within a single ViewModel, if that is the best design option. Especially if your multiple Trees / Collections are filtered from some 'complete set'; it might actually make more sense.

Just add multiple collections to your ViewModel, and bind to them.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> FirstTreeCollection 
    { 
        get
        {
            // whatever you need to do here
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> SecondTreeCollection 
    { 
        get { /* etc */ }
        set { /* etc */ }
    }
    // etc

    public bool Collapsed
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and your Views should bind accordingly

```
// in your first view that contains a tree
<UserControl x:Class="View1" ...>
    <TreeView Name="FirstTree" 
              ItemsSource={Binding FirstTreeCollection}
              Collapsed={Binding Collapsed} ... >

// & in your second view that contains a tree
<UserControl x:Class="View2" ...>
    <TreeView Name="SecondTree" 
              ItemsSource={Binding SecondTreeCollection}
              Collapsed={Binding Collapsed} ... >
```

To clarify, I'm suggesting that you use a **single ViewModel** for all of these Tree-containing Views.

Comment: agreed. but can you elaborate more on how i could implement this?

Comment: not sure how that would work out.. i have only one tree. it's bound to my view model. i just need to bind the 2 properties i mentioned to some shared viewmodel. so in effect my tree view would be bound to 2 different models... not sure how to do that

Comment: see my edit. I'm suggesting you use a single VM for your views that contain a tree.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) and [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) service from it to exchange data between view models.

Comment: very nice, i wasn't aware of that thanks! but looks like that solution is more suitable for event aggregation? or can i also bind boolean view properties to it?

Comment: @Sonic Soul: Create custom class `TreeViewState` derived from `CompositePresentationEvent. Class contains `MyItem` and `bool` - indicates state, and, also identificator of tree view (first or second). Each view model publish events when state changes and subsribes to them.

Answer (score 0):

The ViewModel won't need a DependencyPropery--it will just need to expose a property that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

The two ViewModels will need to have some way of sharing state, and exposing a property that represents that state.  How you share the state depends heavily on how your ViewModels are instantiated (and probably other factors).  For example, if your two VMs are being instantiated by some parent object, the parent may create one instance and pass it to both VMs in their constructors.

Comment: if i understand you correctly, all views would have an instance of the state, and in my Tree markup i'd bind it like this: IsExpanded={Binding MainState.IsExpanded} ?  is that what you had in mind?

Comment: All ViewModels would have an instance of the state.  Then collapsing the state in one area would propagate the change to the shared state, then back down to the views.  That said, if using a single ViewModel like Kirk suggested is an option, that would be a better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you display the treeview's using xaml, you can bind every treeview to the first treeview spawned.

For example you can use some binding like this:

```
<TreeView Name="FirstTreeView" />
<TreeView Name="SecondTree" 
          IsExpended = {Binding Path=IsExpanded, ElementName=FirstTreeView, Mode=TwoWay}/>
```

Comment: but IsExpanded will be different for every TreeViewItem.. how will the second tree view know which nodes to sync to which ones in the first ?

Comment: Are the hierarchical structures the same for all the trees?